# In g++, system() function returns -1

Tags: c++, g++, system

I am looking for the reasons and cases in which the `system()` in C++ Program returns -1. I am in situation where it works fine in a class where doesn't in another class.

Comment: Post some of your code. By the way, if you're talking about the `system` function of the standard library (with the first letter lowercase), a return value of -1 doesn't necessarily mean that there's an error.

Comment: system() returns the exit code of the program you invoked via it.

Comment: This is probably a long shot, but...  Check what you're returning on the failing path and see if the value is out of range for the shell in use.  I remember an older shell on a Linux distribution at one point that returned any value over a certain value as -1.  I don't remember what certain value was or what the shell was.

Answer (score 5):

Let's first consider how the standard describes the `system` function return value :

> If the argument is a null pointer, the system function returns nonzero only if a
>   command processor is available. **If the argument is not a null pointer, and the system
>   function does return, it returns an implementation-defined value**.

I'll assume that your implementation is the gnu libc, so let's refer to [its documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Running-a-Command.html#Running-a-Command) :

> **The return value is -1 if it wasn't possible to create the shell process**, and otherwise is the status of the shell process.

The status ***is not*** the result of the command and can be interpreted using the tools described on [this page](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Process-Completion-Status.html#Process-Completion-Status). In other words, `system()` should never return -1 except in case of shell process creation failure.